# How to encode a json response from google api?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to retrieve a json data from google api i got an arabic value but i have problem with the arabic

My Code

```
 string AddressURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" + Convert.ToString(row["LONGITUDE"]) + "," + Convert.ToString(row["LATITUDE"]) + "&types=point_of_interest&radius=100&sensor=false&key=API_KEY";
                var result1 = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(AddressURL) ;
                var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result1);
```

the response is

"name" : "ظپظ†ط¯ظ‚ ط¬ظˆظ‡ط± ط§ظ„ط¬ظˆط§ط±",

the problem is the Arabic value (  "name" : "**ظپظ†ط¯ظ‚ ط¬ظˆظ‡ط± ط§ظ„ط¬ظˆط§ط±",** )

how can i parse the Arabic value , How could I do in C# .Net

Comment: I fixed the problem

Comment: string INs = result1;
                    byte[] bb = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(result1);
                    result1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb);

Comment: .NET uses Unicode, you don't have to encode/decode anything. Do you have a specific problem? What is it?

Answer (score -1):

```
        string INs = result1;
                byte[] bb = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetBytes(result1);
                result1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb);
```

Thanks i fixed the problem

Comment: That's not a fix. That means there is something wrong with your code because .NET strings are *always* Unicode. This code makes sense *ONLY* if the returned data is ASCII instead of UTF8. Try setting the correct encoding request headers, instead of trying to repair the result after the fact

Comment: Not my downvote, but this answer is bad, bordering on dangerous. You also *don't* provide enough information to replicate the problem. How is anyone going to retrieve the same data when you don't provide the actual URL?

Comment: This is the link      :    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.760200,43.737900&types=point_of_interest&radius=200&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDYshcVjnwqkCJ4UKtPAwBkM50CUWTItUE